# React Native hooks useState - setState array dont work

Tags: react-native, axios, fetch, state, hook

When i try to set state from API, i have response.data but setState dont work.

```
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    cargarItems();
  }, [])

  const cargarItems = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/items');
    const data= await res.json();
    setItems(data);
    console.log(data);
    console.log(items); }
```

Also try:

```
await axios
      .get('http://localhost:4000/api/items')
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(typeof res.data);
        setItems(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
      console.log(items);
```

And allways i get:

[image]

I have the response but the state is not updated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you won't never get data change right after setState. to see how it change, you can try this React.useEffect(()=>{ console.log(items);},[items])

Comment: Thanks! I try to map and it wokrs. Before I map and didnt work, for this reason i useed console.log, but maybe was another mistake.